# Problems using HTML Canvas & Greasemonkey not able to drawImage() on 2D context

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, canvas, greasemonkey

In my Greasemonkey script, when I obtain a handle on an HTMLImageElement I want to use with an HTML Canvas, I get the following error in Firefox's Error Console <strike>(I assume it's because it's enclosed in an XPCNativeWrapper)</strike>:

```
Error: Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) 
       [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]
```

<strike>Putting `GM_log()` statements throughout my code, I have traced the image object I'm trying to use from it's initial assignment through until I try to use it with an HTML Canvas.</strike>

It's always wrapped in an XPCNativeWrapper:

```
[object XPCNativeWrapper [object HTMLImageElement]]
```

I've unwrapped the `HTMLImageElement` by obtaining reference to it with `image.wrappedJSObject`.

My canvas code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Any ideas why Firefox is throwing the above component failure code?

Comment: I've not appended this canvas element to the DOM / body - would this cause a problem?

Comment: Looking at other example code I tried `unsafeWindow.document.createElement("canvas")` but never managed to get this working correctly. Changed my approach, a bit more clumsey, re-requested the image via AJAX with forced MIME type to "text" to read the image data.

Comment: I can't reproduce any bug, because I don't know what `image` is.

Comment: It's just a regular image in an HTML document, mine was 100 x 80 pixels.

Comment: Are you sure the image has finished loading? In other words: is image.complete? It looks like the image data is NOT_AVAILABLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have looked more thoroughly on Google.

```
image.wrappedJSObject;
```

Works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas").wrappedJSObject,
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;

ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

this is what i did. hope it helps

Comment: I just tried this with FF 4.0.1.  The canvas DOM object created this way has no such property "wrappedJSObject".  Were you using FF.  What version?

Comment: It is expected to run in the Greasemonkey context, not in the Firefox context.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. The error went away when I used an absolute/complete URL for the image. Also, as someone else had noted, make sure the image is loaded first of all, or just create a new Image() in javascript first of all.

Answer (score 0):

Working example for firefox 3.6.16 (I had similar problem):

http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/106800